# Python Regular Expressions - Parse Out Port From tcpdump

Tags: python, regex, port, tcpdump

I am attempting to parse out the information given when running "tcpdump -nNqt".

Example output looks like this:

```
IP 10.0.0.11.60446 > 10.0.0.232.22: tcp 0
IP 10.0.0.232.22 > 10.0.0.11.60446: tcp 176
IP 10.0.0.232.22 > 10.0.0.11.60446: tcp 80
```

I have so far been able to remove:

First IP / Second IP

```
(?<=IP\s)\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
(?<=\s>\s)\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

TCP or UDP / Size

```
(?<=:\s)(.{1,3})
(?<=tcp |udp )(\d+)
```

I have not been able to parse out the port numbers which are the final digits at the end of the IP. My nonworking attempt looks like this:

```
(?<=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)\d{,6}
```

What is wrong with my expression? Is there another way of doing this that I am not seeing?

Comment: Why do you want to match the different portions? Why not make ONE regex, which fills all the matches in one go for you (ip1 , port1, ip2, port2, tcp/udp, size), making it a lot easier on yourself? The problem with the regex is probably that your implementation does not support variable-width lookbehinds (in other words: they need to have a predefined width, which the `{1,3}` is not).

Comment: BTW, [there are standard PCAP parsing libs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcapfile)

Comment: also, I can highly recommend pyparsing over the unpythonic mess that are regexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are taking the parts you need one at a time. You could just take them all in one go (I also collapsed your IP pattern a bit):

```
IP (?P<IP1>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\.(?P<Port1>\d+) > (?P<IP2>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\.(?P<Port2>\d+): (?:tc|ud)p (?P<protocol>\d+)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/sU3bM2/1)

```
import re

reg = re.compile(r"IP (?P<IP1>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\.(?P<Port1>\d+) > (?P<IP2>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\.(?P<Port2>\d+): (?:tc|ud)p (?P<size>\d+)")

for line in input_lines:
    m = reg.match(line)
    print(m.group("IP1"))
    print(m.group("Port1"))
    print(m.group("IP2"))
    print(m.group("Port2"))
    print(m.group("size"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just parse the whole thing with one regex? Using groups, you can still separate the different parts. For example:

```
import re

regex_string = r'IP (?P<first_ip>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d+) > (?P<second_ip>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d+): (?P<protocol>tcp|udp) (?P<port_num>\d{1,5})'
ip_regex = re.compile(regex_string)

#info contains the output of tcpdump
for match in ip_regex.finditer(info):
    print(match.group("first_ip"))
    print(match.group("second_ip"))
    print(match.group("protocol"))
    print(match.group("port_num"))
```

[Here's](https://pythex.org/?regex=IP%20(%3FP%3Cfirst_ip%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%2B)%20%3E%20(%3FP%3Csecond_ip%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%2B)%3A%20(%3FP%3Cprotocol%3Etcp%7Cudp)%20(%3FP%3Cport_num%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C5%7D)&test_string=IP%2010.0.0.11.60446%20%3E%2010.0.0.232.22%3A%20tcp%200%0AIP%2010.0.0.232.22%20%3E%2010.0.0.11.60446%3A%20tcp%20176%0AIP%2010.0.0.232.22%20%3E%2010.0.0.11.60446%3A%20tcp%2080%0AIP%2010.0.0.232.22%20%3E%2010.0.0.11.60446%3A%20udp%2080&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) a great website to test regular expressions if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
/^.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*?([a-z]+)\s(\d+)$/g
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wI4kG7/3)